# Date conversion issue while setting region from settings application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I want to convert string to date. Its not working in following situation.
I am using settings application to set region. In settings, go to general, go to international, go to region format, go to spanish and then set Argentina.
After setting these parameter, I try to convert string to date. Its not converting string to date. Please help.

**EDIT :** This is my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ; 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma"];
 NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

Comment: please show your code..

Comment: strDate =@"05/29/2012 6:15PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma"];
    NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];

Comment: It do not able to convert string to date due to region settings I did in device. If I remove that setting from device then its working fine. I want to solve the the problem with settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html) explains what you're experiencing

In short, format your date with the american locale, if you wish to display the date to a user, convert the date to a string.

For example:

```
NSString *strDate  = @"05/29/2012 6:15PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma"];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

And to show the date to a user:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *newDate = [formatter2 stringFromDate:_date];
```

Date strings entering the application should typically be converted to a standard format, should you ever want to display a date to the user, you would need to format the date back to a string - think of them as seperate steps:

1. Get the string to a sane date format
2. Get the date to the users locale with the desired formatting

Answer (score 0):

When you are converting a String to Date, the String must be in Spanish(Argentina) format for the NSDateFormatter to understand.

in your example, the date you passed is "**05/29/2012 6:15PM**"

However, in Spanish(Argentina), the date string should be "**05/29/2012 6:15p.m.**"

*If you are getting this date dynamically, best is to remove the AM/PM component in the date and try getting the Date String in 24-Hour format*

Comment: I am getting string from web service, every time its not possible to handle region setting on server side.

Comment: This is incorrect, the whole purpose of NSDateFormatter is to convert between different date formats.